# Server refused our key

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created a fresh Ubuntu machine and I have created a new .pem file after that I have loaded that .pem in "**Puttykey Generator**" and I have selected save as a private file, So successfully key creation has been completed. And I have tried to login into the "**Putty**" and given user name has ubuntu & tried root as well but getting server refused our key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create a Linux system on AWS you have to choose a Keypair to associate with it. If you don't have one you create it beforehand. That is the ssh private key you need when you log in to that machine.

Comment: Well I have created ssh private key it's working for linux machine but the same key which i have used for Ubuntu machine it's not happening.

Comment: Maybe I am confused about what you are trying to do. If you created a key and want to log in as root with that key, you would need to ensure that the public key (not the pem file... but it can be derived from the pem file) is listed in the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Then you will be able to use the ppk file from putty to log in as root over ssh (assuming you have allowed root login in /etc/ssh/sshd_config).